# margin: 0 auto; isn't working in Firefox and Safari. Works in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Here is my page: http://inventikasolutions.com/demo/tatasky

The blue button appears centered in Google Chrome but in Safari and Firefox it floats to the left.

I'm using the latest version of the browsers.

My css code is:

```
.messi .btn {
background-image: url(submit.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
background-position: -1px -490px;
background-color: #5B74A8;
border-color: #29447E #29447E #1A356E;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
border: 1px solid #999;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}

.messi-actions .btnbox .btn {
min-width: 75px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is rendering the div tags around the btn differently. So it is aligning it to the center of it's wrapping div tag, but that tag is only the width of the button and is left aligned. Add this to get it working:

```
.mesi-footbox {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will center the div if it doesn't render full width, or leave things the same in chrome.

Comment: your edit works on Firefox but Safari is still broken. Safari too uses webkit, so why is it not rendering the layout properly?
Chrome is rendering it the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

@Pritesh Desai
try to put in safari
text-align:center; to the container div which contains the div you want to be centered